# Can I specify a limited character set for XSL output?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, plaintext

I'm using XSL to convert UTF-8 XML to plaintext, and it's going to ASCII-only systems. A mainframe, among others. There are a whole raft of characters that can potentially be in the XML that will choke the downstream systems. The purpose in existence of this XSL is to service those downstream systems, so it's my responsibility to give them usable files.

I have LOTS of different XSL that's doing this.

I've patched some of the critical XSL to use `translate()` to replace some specific chars I knew were coming across and causing difficulty, but only as a stop-gap. I can't afford to do that for every character in the extended set, for every field in every XSL I'm running.

I have zero control over the encoding or character set of the XML. Is there a way that I can simply, programmatically, cause the XSL to only use ASCII characters in the plaintext file that it creates? Some kind of specification in the output declaration?

EDIT: To be more precise, it's important that I not remove any characters. As I'm doing now, with `translate()`, I need to replace the non-ASCII characters with readable alternatives. Ideally, there's a way to tell XSL to use some standardized method to replace non-ASCII characters with ASCII.

Secondly, I cannot throw any errors. I don't have any control over the sending system, so if there are any errors, it's not as if I can say "hey, this record failed, please resend it with only ASCII characters."

Thirdly, I have some control over the process, so I could put an additional XSL that just translates the characters before passing it along. That's not a bad idea, because I'd only have to maintain one extra transform. However, there are almost 100 transforms for me to maintain, so I'd have to modify almost all of their pipelines. That might actually be a good alternative, if there's not an easy way in XSL.

The `<xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"/>` idea sounds like what I'm after, but I'll have to experiment and see what the character references look like coming out the other end. That might be a good option.

Comment: Well, there is `<xsl:output encoding="US-ASCII"/>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#XML_ENCODING for what it does, if you have an element name containing a non ASCII character you will get an error, if you have data containing a non ASCII character, that character will be output as a character reference.

Comment: If the output method is `text` then according to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#TEXT_ENCODING you will get an error for non ASCII data if you choose `encoding="US-ASCII"`.

Comment: Are the character entity references that @MartinHonnen refers to acceptable? Or, even better than what you doing now?

Comment: Could you run two XSLTs, the first to transform all `text()` values, the second to format XML to text? XSL might not be the best tool for this transformation, anyway. (If I had to, I'd use my [msxsl:script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script) hammer.) Can you insert another process into the pipeline to filter or transliterate characters after XSL step?

Comment: Unfortunately, XSL is my only option. I'd much rather be dealing with almost anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really explained in what way you want to treat non-ASCII letters but as you have tagged the question as [xslt-2.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-2.0) you have access to the XPath/XSLT 2.0 regular expressions so for instance to remove any non-ASCII characters from any text nodes you could use `replace`:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[^\r\n\t&#x0020;-&#x007E;]+', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Another way to write the replacement would be

```
  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\P{IsBasicLatin}+', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

There is also the `normalize-unicode` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-unicode if you don't want to simply remove all non-ASCII characters.

Comment: This is a good idea. It's very similar to what I'm doing now, but saves me the trouble of specifying every character and every replacement. The one drawback (as with `translate()`) is that I have in some cases 150 or more elements to "clean" before writing them out to a text file. Lots of places to add a `replace()` call. Also, the system I'm writing for doesn't allow all XSL functionality, or I'd write an `xsl:function` with `replace` or `translate` in it and just use it to write out the values.

Comment: If you want to strip the non-ASCII characters from all text in the input then the above template should do that, independent of any parent or ancestor element name. So I don't see why you would need to use `replace` in 150 places. But you haven't shown any of your existing transformation. It might be better to ask a new question on how to simplify your stylesheet.

Comment: No, I just missed that part. I'm still new to XSL, so it wasn't obvious to me that this didn't have to be a per-element thing.